# Need help resolving javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, apache-httpclient-4.x

I'm using Apache httpcomponents 4.2.5 to build a simple https client to get a file from a server.

The code is based primarily off of the [ClientExecuteProxy.java](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientProxyAuthentication.java) sample code.  I developed and tested the client under Java 1.6.0_31 and it works as expected.

I distributed the final jar to one of my servers which has Java 1.7.0_25 (miraculously installed about 2 weeks ago).  Under Java 7 is when I get the error.

I've tried a number of switches, accessed the site through firefox, clicked the lock and downloaded the certificate/added to cacerts.  This is verified in the debug log below, note that it worked without it under java 6.  I continue to get the same stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:493)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:232)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.layerProtocol(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:401)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:840)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:647)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:827)
```

Turned on the javax debug option and see what everyone else is posting...

```
    executing request to https://dmf.ntis.gov:443 via http://myproxy.mynet:8080
trustStore is: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts
trustStore type is : jks
trustStore provider is : 
init truststore

...

adding as trusted cert:
  Subject: CN=dmf.ntis.gov, O=National Technical Information Service, L=Alexandria, ST=Virginia, C=US
  Issuer:  CN=Entrust Certification Authority - L1C, OU="(c) 2009 Entrust, Inc.", OU=www.entrust.net/rpa is incorporated by reference, O="Entrust, Inc.", C=US
  Algorithm: RSA; Serial number: 0x4c1ed933
  Valid from Fri Jan 25 10:23:19 EST 2013 until Sun Jan 26 22:54:05 EST 2014

...

trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Allow unsafe renegotiation: true
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1355254829 bytes = { 151, 204, 236, 54, 121, 42, 132, 221, 43, 116, 69, 16, 51, 17, 65, 109, 23, 135, 125, 16, 54, 72, 163, 189, 169, 189, 114, 223 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1, sect233k1, sect233r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, secp384r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2, sect163r1, secp192k1, sect193r1, sect193r2, secp224k1, sect239k1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: dmf.ntis.gov]
***
[write] MD5 and SHA1 hashes:  len = 170
0000: 01 00 00 A6 03 01 51 C8   8C 2D 97 CC EC 36 79 2A  ......Q..-...6y*
0010: 84 DD 2B 74 45 10 33 11   41 6D 17 87 7D 10 36 48  ..+tE.3.Am....6H
0020: A3 BD A9 BD 72 DF 00 00   2A C0 09 C0 13 00 2F C0  ....r...*...../.
0030: 04 C0 0E 00 33 00 32 C0   07 C0 11 00 05 C0 02 C0  ....3.2.........
0040: 0C C0 08 C0 12 00 0A C0   03 C0 0D 00 16 00 13 00  ................
0050: 04 00 FF 01 00 00 53 00   0A 00 34 00 32 00 17 00  ......S...4.2...
0060: 01 00 03 00 13 00 15 00   06 00 07 00 09 00 0A 00  ................
0070: 18 00 0B 00 0C 00 19 00   0D 00 0E 00 0F 00 10 00  ................
0080: 11 00 02 00 12 00 04 00   05 00 14 00 08 00 16 00  ................
0090: 0B 00 02 01 00 00 00 00   11 00 0F 00 00 0C 64 6D  ..............dm
00A0: 66 2E 6E 74 69 73 2E 67   6F 76                    f.ntis.gov
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 170
[Raw write]: length = 175
0000: 16 03 01 00 AA 01 00 00   A6 03 01 51 C8 8C 2D 97  ...........Q..-.
0010: CC EC 36 79 2A 84 DD 2B   74 45 10 33 11 41 6D 17  ..6y*..+tE.3.Am.
0020: 87 7D 10 36 48 A3 BD A9   BD 72 DF 00 00 2A C0 09  ...6H....r...*..
0030: C0 13 00 2F C0 04 C0 0E   00 33 00 32 C0 07 C0 11  .../.....3.2....
0040: 00 05 C0 02 C0 0C C0 08   C0 12 00 0A C0 03 C0 0D  ................
0050: 00 16 00 13 00 04 00 FF   01 00 00 53 00 0A 00 34  ...........S...4
0060: 00 32 00 17 00 01 00 03   00 13 00 15 00 06 00 07  .2..............
0070: 00 09 00 0A 00 18 00 0B   00 0C 00 19 00 0D 00 0E  ................
0080: 00 0F 00 10 00 11 00 02   00 12 00 04 00 05 00 14  ................
0090: 00 08 00 16 00 0B 00 02   01 00 00 00 00 11 00 0F  ................
00A0: 00 00 0C 64 6D 66 2E 6E   74 69 73 2E 67 6F 76     ...dmf.ntis.gov
main, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
main, called closeSocket()
main, IOException in getSession():  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

Sorry for the Long Post here.  This log was generated using the -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true switch, but it made no difference.

The code has some custom classes, but there's no magic here.  The configuration is in property files and loaded at runtime, parameters should be pretty self explanatory.

```
    private static void getHttpFile(HttpContextConfig cfg,
        HttpContextEntry ctx, 
        String remoteFile, 
        String localFile, 
        Boolean useTemp) throws Exception {


    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    System.out.println("\n\n" + sdf.format(new Date()) +  " HttpClientUtil Starting...");

    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    // socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "SSLv3" }); 
    try {
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost(ctx.getHostName(), 
                Integer.parseInt(ctx.getPort()), 
                ctx.getScheme());

        if (null != cfg.getProxyHost()){
            HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(cfg.getProxyHost(), 
                    cfg.getProxyPort(), 
                    cfg.getProxyScheme());

            httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
            System.out.println("executing request to " + target + " via " + proxy);
        }
        else
            System.out.println("executing request to " + target);

        // Set the credentials if we have a userID
        if (null != ctx.getUserName()){
            httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(
                    new AuthScope(ctx.getHostName(), Integer.parseInt(ctx.getPort())),
                    new UsernamePasswordCredentials(ctx.getUserName(), ctx.getPassword()));
        }


        HttpGet req = new HttpGet(remote);

        HttpResponse rsp = httpclient.execute(target, req);
        HttpEntity entity = rsp.getEntity();

        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
        System.out.println(rsp.getStatusLine());
        Header[] headers = rsp.getAllHeaders();
        for (int i = 0; i<headers.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(headers[i]);
        }
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        System.out.println("\n\t" + sdf.format(new Date()) +  " Writing Output to File: " + local );

            *** Snipped some unimportant code out ***

            OutputStream OutStream = new FileOutputStream(local);

            entity.writeTo(OutStream);
            OutStream.flush();
            OutStream.close();

    } finally {
        // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed,
        // shut down the connection manager to ensure
        // immediate deallocation of all system resources
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

I have been plowing through various threads, trying to figure out the answer.  I don't want to disable (accept all certificates) solution.  I haven't tried the custom SSL socket factory for explicitly setting SSLv3 negotiation.

> socket.setEnabledProtocols(new String[] { "SSLv3" });

This site does have a user id and password in order to download data, and does have cookies, but again, this does work under JRE 6.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question ended up being a multitude of things.

1. The production servers were using WPAD (Web Proxy Auto Discovery)
   proxy lookup.  I was using a proxy that was reachable, but not
   really configured for the host I was using. I ended up using [proxy-vole](https://code.google.com/p/proxy-vole/) to avoid hard-coded proxy servers in properties files.
2. Java 7 changed the behavior of the httpclient.  I copied the JRE 7 from my production host to my local pc and was challenged with Authentication from my proxy server.  This didn't happen in JRE 6.  In the Windows environment, I resolved this by using NTLM Proxy Authentication

> ```
> DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
> httpclient.getAuthSchemes().register("ntlm", new NTLMSchemeFactory());
> ```

Strangely enough, I didn't see the Proxy Authentication issue until I ran the code against a valid Proxy Server/Host combination.  I'm sure it's a configuration thing, but the proxy server returned a not authenticated page with the proper configuration.  On my production servers, I just got the socket disconnect.

Unfortunately this is one of those 30,000 foot errors that seems to have a number of root causes.

Comment: Hi Mike I am getting the peer authentication issue from AWS and plivo servers. From AWS I tried to register an endpoint on plivo. But getting this error, for the same build which was working fine in older days.